# Losing collection objects that are passed to a web service as properties of another object

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services, collections

I have a very complex ASP.Net web service that I am having to develop.  Below is sample code that I've written.

First, I have a web service method that takes a List as a parameter.

[WebMethod]  public AppResults SyncObjectToServer(string appID, List updates)

`WSExecCommand` is a class that I've defined that contains a multiple List objects.  Here is a simplistic version of `WSExecCommand`.

```
[Serializable] public class WSExecCommand
{
    public string Command;

    [XmlIgnore] public Dictionary<string, MyKeyValuePair> __ParentKey;
    [XmlArray] public List<MyKeyValuePair> ParentKey
    { 
        get
        {
            if (__ParentKey == null)
                __ParentKey = new Dictionary<string, MyKeyValuePair>;
            return new List<KeyValuePair>(__ParentKey.Values); 
        }
        set
        {
            __ParentKey.Clear();
            foreach (MyKeyValuePair kvp in value)
                __ParentKey.Add(kvp.Key, kvp);
        }
    }
}
```

If you are wondering why I've setup my class this way, the problem is that ASP.Net doesn't allow for you to return or receive Dictionary objects.  I really need for my `ParentKey` object to be a dictionary.  However, to get around the limitations of ASP.Net, I created the above wrapper property to get and set the values of the underlying Dictionary, which I reference in my code.

My problem is that when I call my web service method from my consuming application, `__ParentKey` is never populated with the data that is being passed to the server.

I've stepped into the Web Service code, and I am getting a populated `List<WSExecCommand>` collection.  However, for each `WSExecCommand` in the list, all `List<T>` type objects have 0 items.

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
get
{
    if (__ParentKey == null)
        __ParentKey = new Dictionary<string, MyKeyValuePair>;
    return new List<KeyValuePair>(__ParentKey.Values); 
}
```

Looks like here you're setting __ParentKey to a new Dictionary, and then returning a list of the KeyValuePairs in that dictionary, which of course would be empty the first time you call it.  Since you've chosen to not serialize `__ParentKey` (which you can't anyways, because Dictionaries are not serializable), when the instance of `WSExecCommand` is deserialized on the other end of the wire, then `__ParentKey` is null (which then results in an empty list the first time you try to access the property).

**EDIT**

It is possible that the setter is being called on deserialization like you'd expect.  However, if that is the case then your problem is likely the fact that `__ParentKey` is null when you construct the object, and does not get instantiated until you call the getter the first time.  I do not believe that your getter would be called during deserialization, and as a result the instance of your dictionary is never created.  Try constructing your dictionary up front, and that way you could remove the null check from your getter as well.

```
[Serializable] public class WSExecCommand
{
    public string Command;

    [XmlIgnore] public Dictionary<string, MyKeyValuePair> __ParentKey = 
         new Dictionary<string, MyKeyValuePair>();
    [XmlArray] public List<MyKeyValuePair> ParentKey
    { 
        get
        {
            return new List<KeyValuePair>(__ParentKey.Values); 
        }
        set
        {
            __ParentKey.Clear();
            foreach (MyKeyValuePair kvp in value)
                __ParentKey.Add(kvp.Key, kvp);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Mike, I actually added that `__ParentKey` null check because, otherwise, something was broken within .Net.  I couldn't step into my Web Service from my test cases.  I'm not sure how ASP.Net takes the XML requests and converts them to the appropriate types.  However, I added the null check just so that the Dictionary would exist.  Do you have any clue how I can fix this conundrum?!

Comment: It's not broken in .NET.  You're not serializing the value of __ParentKey when you send it to or from the service, and as a result on the other side it will always be null.  Like I said in my answer, since you cannot serialize a `Dictionary` you will have to come up with another way to get the data you need into a field that is serializable so that it can be transferred over the wire.  From there you can do whatever work you need to get it back from that intermediate format into the `Dictionary` you want.

Comment: Sorry if I seem dense, but that was the purpose of the List property, in the first place.  I can see this list object from my auto-generated class, in my test console application.  It was my assumption that once ASP.Net deserialized my XML request, it would convert my XML Array, to a List<KeyValuePair> and attempt to set it through the setter.  The setter code would then initialize the Dictionary.  I could, certainly, try to find a way to do this a different way.  However, my approach made logical sense to me.

Comment: It's possible, I'm more used to DataContract serialization for WCF over XML Serialization.  From the receiving application (the one you are sending this object TO not from) put a breakpoint in the setter and let me know if that is being hit during deserialization.  Also see if you can figure out what the `value` it is setting is.  If it's an empty list, then you'll know it's being lost on the original serialization

Comment: Hey Mike C, I'm giving you the answer mark because this did help me fix the problem, though not in a manner that I would prefer.  Anyway, the reason why I instantiated the `__ParentKey` is because when I put breakpoints on the getter and setter, the getter was always being accessed, first, before the setter.  So, my thought was, instantiate the getter and, then, any calls to set or add to the list should automagically work.  There might be a way to fix this, but I've moved on.  Thank's for suggesting to try something different.